# How to override password_change error messages in django?

Tags: django, validation, templates, forms

I have spent ages on the net how to override the change_password form in django. I created my forms and I can change my passwords successfully. Now I want to display my errors on the page.
(By the way , I'm using django-registration.)

The problem is I have to change error messages. In my template I'm using this function to display new_password1 errors :

```
{% if form.new_password1.errors %}
     <div class="error_message"> blah </div>
{% endif %}
```

However it consists of  all new_password1 errrors. I looked the docs and found that CharField has only reqiured, max and min. I need to check each specific errors of the new_password1 (confirmation error, required error and min,max) and produce my own error messages. Since the CharField doesn't have a matching keyword, I tried a clean method in my forms.py which looks like :

```
 def clean_password2(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        if  'new_password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'new_password2' in self.cleaned_data:                                                                                                                                                                   
            if self.cleaned_data['new_password1'] != self.cleaned_data['new_password2']:                                                                                                                                                                     
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(u"no match"))                                                                                                                                                                                                

        return cleaned_data
```

Finally, I don't know how to check this clean_password2 validation in my template. When I wrote registration page, I can display all my errors by looping the errors. And it displays all overrided errors. This time it doesn't work. So my quesstions are:

1- How can i check all specific errors in my templates ? like if form.new_password1.required.errors

2- How can i display this clean_password2 messages ?

Answer (score 2):

In django-speak, what you're referring to as the view is the template. It's rather confusing!

Update: I see that you define a `clean_password2` function but you are checking for fields called `new_password1`, `new_password2`.

Unless you have a field called `password2`, **that** is the field that your clean method is validating.

The messages for `clean_password2` are generated in `{{ form.password2.errors }}`, but to me, it sounds like you don't have a field called `password2`.

Change the name of your method to `clean_new_password2`.

```
{% if form.new_password1.errors %}{{ form.new_password1.errors }}{% endif %} 
{% if form.new_password2.errors %}{{ form.new_password2.errors }}{% endif %}
```

Form field cleaning works per field.. you access the errors off the field object.

Comment: sorry, i don't know why I wrote views, I've changed them =) 
I tried your advice but it didn't give any messages. I replaced password1 with new_password1 and it gives This field is required. password2 doesn't give any response in both cases.

Comment: Ah, I see. Somehow I missed the part in your code where I see you have a `clean_password2` defined but your fields are named `new_password1` and 2. Updating my post..

Answer (score 0):

Like @Yuji said, use `{% if form.non_field_errors %}` in your template.

Now just a bit on usability. Concerning the user registration and password change form, the only non-field errors your can expect will be mismatching passwords, so unlike other forms where your going to print the non-field errors at the very beginning, for these forms it makes sense to print the one non-field error before the two password input fields, possibly wrapping them in a parent that has a red background, to make it more obvious that the values of the two fields are related and that the error concerns the two fields, not the form in general.